# PgaSocketWriteAllUnix meaning?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat, eclipse-adt

In LogCat I am getting Text as "PgaSocketWriteAllUnix : send () failed : err 2 ".
What does it mean ? I am using eclipse IDE for Android Application Development.

Comment: I'm just meet that error too, Waiting for a reason and solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with the emulator system image. Find the discussion on this error here :

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/ISQTL0YxUuY

Many people resolved this issue by uninstalling BlueStack. Try uninstalling if you have BlueStack installed.

Comment: Thanks.Helps But I would still like to know why this happens and what this error mean .

Comment: that's a bug actually with 4.2 updates of android, if you'll see the thread I have shared you, the man from android os developer team has mentioned that they're trying to resolve it.